# How to open an HFS+ file by file ID?

Tags: macos

Given an HFS+/HFS volume and the catalog node ID (CNID) of a file it should be possible to open that file, and [technote 1150](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10002989) describes the algorithm for doing just that, yet nowhere can I find the corresponding API 
call.

As far as I can tell, the whole API requires either the file's name or its parent catalog node ID.

What gives?

Comment: Please, is the catalog file the only file that you wish to open? If so: what's the purpose, the desired end result?

Comment: I was working on a never released HFS+ file recovery tool. I think I wanted to poke around inside the catalog file of a healthy, mounted volume without having to open the device with root privileges, which may have required unmounting it. I abandoned the project when I was seduced away by the appstore. And HFS+'s structure makes it very hard to recover deliberately deleted files. I'd already gotten my files back.

Comment: Ah, the seduction! I'm glad your files were recovered. Apple Open Source CopyHFSMeta (currently in [hfs-191.1](http://opensource.apple.com/source/hfs/hfs-191.1/)) might have been fun for you but I know of only one use of the binary, which requires a volume to be unmounted.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the volfs?

Legacy document: [Technical Q&A QA1113: The "/.vol" directory and "volfs"](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#qa/qa2001/qa1113.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001661)

Comment: I'm trying to open the catalog file (CNID 5), however I can't figure out a volume ID. -100 doesn't seem to cut it.

Comment: Got it, but opening /.vol/234881026/5 doesn't seem to work, unfortunately. Would have been a nice, if undocumented, shortcut. Thanks.

Comment: Volfs doesn't expose the catalogue file. Search for hfsdebug to see how you might work with that.